# Populating a textarea from several textfields

Tags: javascript, string

I have several textfields which will populate a text area.

I managed to populate it with a javascript function. On the onblur event of a textfield, the value of the textfield is passed and the textarea is field with this value.

However, my problem is the following:

If I modify a previously filled textfield, the textarea will simply append it again.

What I need is some functionality that if:

1: If I give focus to the textfield which is already been filled and I don't modify it, it will not be appended (I implemented this with an if statement and substring.
2: If I modify a previously filled textfield, the text area DOES NOT append it again at the end of the string BUT it replaces the part of the textarea with just that text field new value.

Take for instance the following 2 textfields:

```
<input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" />
<input type="text" id="txtSurname" name="txtSurname" />
```

If I fill up these textfields with John and Doe respectively, the textarea value will become:

```
txtName=John,txtSurname="Doe"
```

I managed to implement this.

What I need is that if I edit txtName from John to Alex, the textarea value will be as follows:

```
txtName=Alex,txtSurname=Doe
```

and not like is currently being displayed, i.e.

```
txtName=John,txtSurname=Doe,txtName=Alex
```

Should I achieve this by using an array which will store all the textfields values?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following code should work for you. I have wrapped the textboxes inside a div. and also registered a `onkeyup` event on both the textboxes.

The javascript code iterates through each textboxe inside the div, and prints its name and value in the textarea.

**HTML**

> ```
> <div id="textBoxContainer">
>     <input type="text" id="txtName" onkeyup="UpdateTextArea();" name="txtName" />  
>     <input type="text" id="txtSurname"  onkeyup="UpdateTextArea();" name="txtSurname" />  
> </div>  
> <textarea id="textAreaResult"></textarea>
> ```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function UpdateTextArea() {
        var textBoxContainerDiv = document.getElementById("textBoxContainer");
        var textboxes = textBoxContainerDiv.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var finalResult = "";
        var textAreaFinalResult = document.getElementById("textAreaResult");

        for (var i = 0; i < textboxes.length; i++) {
            finalResult = finalResult + textboxes[i].id + "=" + textboxes[i].value + ",";
        }

        textAreaFinalResult.value = finalResult;
    }
</script>
```

**Hope this Helps!** :)

Comment: Thank you! this helped a lot. Now I need to reverse engineer this. I need to populate the textfields if I populate the textarea with this particular format. How can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: okay, one thing I would like to ask related to `Reverse Engineering`, the textboxes will be pre-created or I should create them as user types the name and value for each input box in the textarea?

Comment: Never mind that, as we discussed that for ordering purposes, it would be better to be kept one way (from text box to textarea). Now what I need to do is to populate the textarea with ONLY the textfields which are required to be filled. The way its currently implemented, it loops through all the input fields. How can I achieve this (maybe getting the inputs with the class name required for instance?) thanks

Comment: All right, I managed to get the elements by class instead of by tagname. Many thanks for your help Zain, you saved my day :)

Answer (score -1):

For the record, I feel like this code is an ugly hack, but it should do the trick...

```
    var fieldName = "txtName"; //your field name
    var newValue = "Alex"; //your new value
    var value = document.getElementById("my-textarea").value;
    value = "," + value; //add a comma so we can ensure we don't replace the wrong value where the fieldname is a substring of another fieldname
    if(value.indexOf("," + fieldName + "=") > 0) //see if a value is already defined
    {
        var index = value.indexOf("," + fieldName + "=") + fieldName.length + 2;
        var start = value.substring(0, index); //get the portion before the value
        var end = value.substring(index); //get everything else
        if(end.indexOf(",") > 0)
        {
            end = end.substring(end.indexOf(",")); //remove the value by reducing the end to the location of the next comma
        }else{
            end = ""; //if there isn't another comma it was the last value in the list, so set the new end to nothing
        }
        value = start + newValue + end; 
        value = value.substring(1); //remove the starting comma we gave it
        document.getElementById("my-textarea").value = value;
    }else{
        //append it to the end as you are already doing
    }
```