# Populating anchor link from several textfields

Tags: javascript, string, dom-events

I try to populate several textfields to become something like this `<a href="check.php?name=john doe&group=metallica">Check</a>`

Below is my script that I modified from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089472/populating-a-textarea-from-several-textfields) but this script is only show inside textarea and how to show inside anchor link and generate something like `<a href="check.php?name=john doe&group=metallica">Check</a>`.

```
<div id="textBoxContainer">
    <input type="text" id="name" onkeyup="UpdateTextArea();" name="name" />  
    <input type="text" id="group"  onkeyup="UpdateTextArea();" name="group" />  
</div>  
<textarea id="textAreaResult"></textarea>

<a href="check.php?" id="link_check">Check</a>



<script type="text/javascript">
    function UpdateTextArea() {
        var textBoxContainerDiv = document.getElementById("textBoxContainer");
        var textboxes = textBoxContainerDiv.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var finalResult = "";
        var textAreaFinalResult = document.getElementById("textAreaResult");
    
        for (var i = 0; i < textboxes.length; i++) {
            finalResult = finalResult + textboxes[i].id + "=" + textboxes[i].value + "&";
        }
    
        textAreaFinalResult.value = finalResult;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to say that rather than updating a `textarea` you want to update the `href` of an anchor tag?

Comment: yes.. sorry i still newbie in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to target an anchor tag instead of the textarea, then obviously you need to change that accordingly:

```
<a id="hrefResult" href="check.php">link</a>
```

Then in your `updateTextArea` function, you need to target the anchor's `href` rather than the textarea's `value`. There's several other optimizations that can be made in there also, such as making an array of name/value pairs and then doing a `join` on them so you don't end up with the trailing `&`, etc.

```
function UpdateTextArea() {
    var textBoxContainerDiv = document.getElementById("textBoxContainer");
    var textboxes = textBoxContainerDiv.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var length = textboxes.length;
    var target = document.getElementById("hrefResult");
    var params = [];
    var baseref = 'check.php';

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        params.push(textboxes[i].id + "=" + textboxes[i].value);
    }
    target.href = baseref + '?' + params.join('&');
}
```

What the heck, here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ultranaut/unMsn/) of the whole thing.

It would probably make sense to change the name of the function itself since there's no textarea involved anymore, but I leave that as something for you to do.

Comment: No problem. I just noticed that you had actually already made an anchor tag to target, I missed that at first.